# Not understanding mysql statement DATE_ADD(NOW() INTERVAL)

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a page which contains the following line of mysql. The overal objective is simply to match the current week num to the current date

```
$sql = "select distinct weekNum from " . DB_PREFIX . "schedule where DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR)"
```

[As per my research](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp) `DATE_ADD()` allows you to add a certain number of days to a date.

Thus I am assuming `DATE_ADD(NOW()` adds the current date to...well date?

What exactly does `INTERVAL` do in this statment.

Any help interms of an explanation clarifying above statment will be much appreciated.

Comment: `DATE_ADD` also allows hours to be added to a date.  Your code just appears to be adjusting a timestamp with a server offset.  By the way, consider using prepared statements.

Comment: Hey @TimBiegeleisen thanks for input. Its not my code hence no prepared statement and me struggling to understand the above code.

Comment: After my comment, what isn't clear to you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I got it. It works like this according to my understanding simply get all fixtures where current date is less than match start date. Use SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET is a constant to ensure user time matches EST time (The less than part is added in next line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see this statement is trying to manage timezone difference

```
 INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR
```

should return difference(in hours) for different timezone(server and offset) which is then added to current date to calculate actual time for scheduling.

from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

*DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr unit), DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr unit)
These functions perform date arithmetic. The date argument specifies the starting date or datetime value. expr is an expression specifying the interval value to be added or subtracted from the starting date. expr is a string; it may start with a - for negative intervals. unit is a keyword indicating the units in which the expression should be interpreted.*

Answer (score 4):

```
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOURS)
```

-- This will add 2 hours to the current time

-- The format is `DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL value unit)`

value can be anything --> a number

unit will be -- > anything from following list

```
MICROSECOND
SECOND
MINUTE
HOUR
DAY
WEEK
MONTH
QUARTER
YEAR
SECOND_MICROSECOND
MINUTE_MICROSECOND
MINUTE_SECOND
HOUR_MICROSECOND
HOUR_SECOND
HOUR_MINUTE
DAY_MICROSECOND
DAY_SECOND
DAY_MINUTE
DAY_HOUR
YEAR_MONTH
```

So you can add minutes , Hours , months into your date using this function

Like that you can use the function DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL value unit) Which will substract the date hope you are clear. for more information just visit the link   [https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp]

Answer (score 3):

It takes a date - is this case "now" and ads some hours to it.
In this case it reads the server timezone offset and adds that.

The result would be a date where you get a selection based on the GMT-0 based time.

Answer (score 2):

The function `DATE_ADD()` has two parameters:
  1. the date to which you want to add any interval
  2. the amount of units with key words INTERVAL the numbe UNITS, where 'UNITS'  can be any supported time value between MILLISECONDS ~ YEAR

[The DATE_ADD() is the synonym of ADDDATE().](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-adddate-function.php)